# Room: Cannot access database on the main thread *but*

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I've got this piece of code that I'm trying to run in my Android app:

```
            ServerDatabase.getInstance(ListServersActivity.this).serverDao().getAll().observe(ListServersActivity.this, new Observer<List<Server>>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(List<Server> servers) {
                    serverListAdapter.setServers(servers);
                }
            });
```

I'm trying to run that on the UI thread, so I'm getting this error that looks pretty straight forward and there are lots of entries about it in StackOverflow:

> Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially
>   lock the UI for a long period of time

Now, the problem with this and what makes it different from previous questions I think, is that I'm running it in the main thread on purpose calling runOnUiThread *because* when I was doing it in a background thread I've got this other error:

> Cannot invoke observe on a background thread

So screwed if I run it on the main thread, and screwed if I run it on a background thread. How do I solve this conundrum?

Adding more info, ServerDao is a Room Dao interface so the actual implemenation is generated by Room. This is the declaration of the involved method:

```
public interface ServerDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM server ORDER BY id ASC")
    LiveData<List<Server>> getAll();
// ...
}
```

This is the stack when running in the background thread:

> 2020-03-13 13:36:37.684 24241-24939/com.daon.identityx.docscan
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-13
>       Process: com.daon.identityx.docscan, PID: 24241
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot invoke observe on a background thread
>           at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.assertMainThread(LiveData.java:443)
>           at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.observe(LiveData.java:171)
>           at com.daon.identityx.docscan.ui.activity.ListServersActivity.initRecyclerViewAdapter(ListServersActivity.java:92)
>           at com.daon.identityx.docscan.ui.activity.ListServersActivity.access$000(ListServersActivity.java:33)
>           at com.daon.identityx.docscan.ui.activity.ListServersActivity$1.run(ListServersActivity.java:62)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 2020-03-13 13:36:37.856 24241-24939/com.daon.identityx.docscan
>   E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot invoke
>   observe on a background thread
>           at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.assertMainThread(LiveData.java:443)
>           at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.observe(LiveData.java:171)
>           at com.daon.identityx.docscan.ui.activity.ListServersActivity.initRecyclerViewAdapter(ListServersActivity.java:92)
>           at com.daon.identityx.docscan.ui.activity.ListServersActivity.access$000(ListServersActivity.java:33)
>           at com.daon.identityx.docscan.ui.activity.ListServersActivity$1.run(ListServersActivity.java:62)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 2020-03-13 13:36:37.899 24241-24595/com.daon.identityx.docscan E/CrashlyticsCore:
>   Unexpected method invoked on AppMeasurement.EventListener:
>   onEvent(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle,
>   java.lang.Long); returning null 2020-03-13 13:36:54.223
>   24960-25084/com.daon.identityx.docscan E/FirebaseCrash: Unable to
>   parse Json response string to get message: No value for crashes

And this is the stack when running in the UI thread:

> 2020-03-13 13:45:17.552 26410-26410/com.daon.identityx.docscan
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.daon.identityx.docscan, PID: 26410
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.daon.identityx.docscan/com.daon.identityx.docscan.ui.activity.ListServersActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main
>   thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3114)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3257)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
>        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a
>   long period of time.
>           at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotMainThread(RoomDatabase.java:267)
>           at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:323)
>           at androidx.room.util.DBUtil.query(DBUtil.java:83)
>           at com.daon.identityx.docscan.database.models.ServerDao_Impl.getCount(ServerDao_Impl.java:300)
>           at com.daon.identityx.docscan.repository.ServerDatabase.addDefaultDataIfEmpty(ServerDatabase.java:30)
>           at com.daon.identityx.docscan.repository.ServerDatabase.getInstance(ServerDatabase.java:23)
>           at com.daon.identityx.docscan.ui.activity.ListServersActivity.initRecyclerViewAdapter(ListServersActivity.java:88)
>           at com.daon.identityx.docscan.ui.activity.ListServersActivity.onCreate(ListServersActivity.java:60)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7327)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7318)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3094)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3257) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965) 
>   2020-03-13 13:45:17.694 26410-26410/com.daon.identityx.docscan
>   E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.daon.identityx.docscan/com.daon.identityx.docscan.ui.activity.ListServersActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main
>   thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3114)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3257)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
>        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a
>   long period of time.
>           at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotMainThread(RoomDatabase.java:267)
>           at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:323)
>           at androidx.room.util.DBUtil.query(DBUtil.java:83)
>           at com.daon.identityx.docscan.database.models.ServerDao_Impl.getCount(ServerDao_Impl.java:300)
>           at com.daon.identityx.docscan.repository.ServerDatabase.addDefaultDataIfEmpty(ServerDatabase.java:30)
>           at com.daon.identityx.docscan.repository.ServerDatabase.getInstance(ServerDatabase.java:23)
>           at com.daon.identityx.docscan.ui.activity.ListServersActivity.initRecyclerViewAdapter(ListServersActivity.java:88)
>           at com.daon.identityx.docscan.ui.activity.ListServersActivity.onCreate(ListServersActivity.java:60)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7327)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7318)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3094)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3257) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965) 
>   2020-03-13 13:45:17.732 26410-26729/com.daon.identityx.docscan
>   E/CrashlyticsCore: Unexpected method invoked on
>   AppMeasurement.EventListener: onEvent(java.lang.String,
>   java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle, java.lang.Long); returning null
>   2020-03-13 13:45:26.315 27259-27416/com.daon.identityx.docscan
>   E/FirebaseCrash: Unable to parse Json response string to get message:
>   No value for crashes

Comment: I recommend that you expand your [mcve] to include the implementation of `getAll()` and the complete stack trace of your crash.

Comment: Your second stack trace is not coming from this code. It is coming from a call to `getCount()` on your `ServerDao`, not `getAll()`.

Comment: Oh FFS! thanks a lot, you're a better observer (no pun intended) than I am. Should I delete this question, or would you like to put that in a proper answer so I can select it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few methods on your DAO. Those that return reactive types like `LiveData`, such as `getAll()`, can be called on the main application thread. Room will arrange to do the work on background threads for you.

However, you also appear to have a `getCount()` method that probably looks something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM something")
public long getCount();
```

That is not returning a reactive type, so it will be a synchronous call. That sort of call you cannot make on the main application thread without encountering the "can't do this on the main application thread" exception.

Either:

- Have this method also return a reactive type
- Only call this method from a background thread
- Switch to Kotlin and coroutines, where you can have the best of both worlds (syntax that looks synchronous even though in reality the I/O is asynchronous)
- Disable the background-thread check via `allowMainThreadQueries()` on your `RoomDatabase.Builder`, and be prepared to be yelled at by co-workers and/or users for doing disk I/O on the main application thread

Comment: Thanks. This is probably a design flaw on my own: when I call getInstance() in my ServerDatabase class (which extends Room database) I check if the database is empty by calling getCount(), and if that's the case I insert some default values, so whilst I wasn't calling explicitly to getCount in my code, I was doing it indirectly. This seems kinda messy now, so I'm going to have to rethink how to check and add the default data if it is missing.

Comment: If you want to package a database in your app to use as a starting point, Room now supports `createFromAsset()` on `RoomDatabase.Builder`. There is also `createFromFile()` if you wanted to download a database and start with that.

Comment: JFTR, on that database prepopulation thing there's something here:
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate

I guess the .db file is expected to be a sqlite3 database file.

Comment: @FranMarzoa: Yes, sorry, I should have been more explicit about that.